# C++ variadic templates with type and non-type argument mixing for recursive inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to achieve this:

```cpp
Foo<int, 5, double, 7> foo_1;
Foo<char, 7> foo_2;

foo_1.Foo<int>::value[4] = 1;
foo_2.Foo<char>::value[1] = 'x';
```

*(This is an oversimplified example, `Foo` would do much more than this.)*

How can I do that with variadic templates?

TLDR;

I know that variadic templates can be used in this way if exclusively types or non-types are used:

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
struct Foo;

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct Foo<T, Args...> : Foo<T>, Foo<Args...> {
    Foo(T t, Args... args) : Foo<T>(t), Foo<Args...>(args...) { }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T> {
    T value;

    Foo<T>(T v) : value(v) {}
};

Foo<int, double, char> f(7, 88.1, 'x');
f.Foo<double>::value = 5;
```

But I do not whether it is possible to pair and mix type and non-type template arguments using variadic templates.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to reinvent `tuple`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep This is an oversimplified example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. You'll have to settle for one of the following:

```
Foo<Bar<int, 5>, Bar<double, 7>> foo_1;
Foo<int, Bar<5>, double, Bar<7>> foo_1;
// ...?
```

If the values are always integral, you could also try this:

```
Foo<int[5], double[7]> foo_1;
```

And then extract elemenet types & extents from each argument.

Comment: For your first example, `Bar` could be `std::array`. For your second it's almost `std::integral_constant` except the type would have to be hard-coded.

Comment: @o11c For the second example you could also use a class with an `auto` template parameter.

Answer (score 4):

> But I do not whether it is possible to pair and mix type and non-type template arguments using variadic templates.

Not with an alternate variadic template. But you can wrap couples of types/sizes.

Suppose you have a `Bar` class as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Bar
 { std::array<T, N>  value; };
```

using class specialization you can have a variadic `Bar` so a variadic list of types **and** a variadic list of sizes

```
template <typename...>
struct Foo;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Ns>
struct Foo<Bar<Ts, Ns>...> : public Bar<Ts, Ns>...
 { };
```

You can use it as follows

```
   Foo<Bar<int, 5>, Bar<double, 7>> foo_1;
   Foo<Bar<char, 7>> foo_2;

   foo_1.Bar<int, 5>::value[4] = 1;
   foo_2.Bar<char, 7>::value[1] = 'x';
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Bar
 { std::array<T, N>  value; };

template <typename...>
struct Foo;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Ns>
struct Foo<Bar<Ts, Ns>...> : public Bar<Ts, Ns>...
 {
 };

int main ()
 {
   Foo<Bar<int, 5>, Bar<double, 7>> foo_1;
   Foo<Bar<char, 7>> foo_2;

   foo_1.Bar<int, 5>::value[4] = 1;
   foo_2.Bar<char, 7>::value[1] = 'x';
 }
```

Comment: Would `template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Ns>` work? I tried earlier but MSVC compiler complains that the variadic part must be the last one in the template argument list.

Comment: @TiborTakács Note the way `Ts` and `Ns` are used. They were used together here as `Bar<Ts, Ns>...`

Comment: @TiborTakács - Observe how are used: `Bar<Ts, Ns>...`. They are wrapped inside `Bar`; this way you have a variadic `Bar` so you can have two parallelized (but also three, or four, etc.) variadic lists of the same length. I've added a full compiling example that compile with both g++ and clang++

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array type as typename, example in your case will become:

```
Foo<std::array<int, 5>, std::array<double, 7> > foo_1(
    std::array<int, 5>{0,0,0,0,0},
    std::array<double, 7>{0,0,0,0,0,0,0});

foo_1.Foo<std::array<int, 5>>::value[4] = 1;
```